# How to group the result in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm doing a query from 1 table and using `UNION` with 2 `select`'s  having different conditions.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT DATE(MAX(RECEIVED)) DT,
             INFO CASH_INFO,
             SUM(IF(TRANS_TYPE = 714, AMOUNT, 0)) TOTAL_CASH,
             '' AS OTHER_INFO,
             0 AS TOTAL_CHEQUE,
             0 AS TOTAL_CREDIT
      FROM PAYMENT
      WHERE LOGIN = 'opensys' 
        AND SOURCE_OF_TRX = '245T2' 
        AND RET_CODE_ID IN (0, 106, 110) 
        AND RECEIVED >= DATE_SUB('2015-09-23 16:30:42', INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
        AND TRANS_TYPE = 714
      GROUP BY INFO
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(MAX(RECEIVED)) DT,
             '' AS CASH_INFO,
             0 AS TOTAL_CASH,    
             INFO OTHER_INFO,
             SUM(IF(TRANS_TYPE = 715, AMOUNT, 0)), -- TOTAL_CHEQUE,
             SUM(IF(TRANS_TYPE = 716, AMOUNT, 0)) -- TOTAL_CREDIT
      FROM PAYMENT
      WHERE LOGIN = 'opensys' 
        AND SOURCE_OF_TRX = '245T2' 
        AND RET_CODE_ID IN (0, 106, 110) 
        AND RECEIVED >= DATE_SUB('2015-09-23 16:30:42', INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
        AND TRANS_TYPE in (715, 716)
      GROUP BY INFO
     ) A
GROUP BY CASH_INFO, OTHER_INFO
ORDER BY DT
```

The result is not really accurate because the record does not group the same date record.

What I wanted to achieve is to group the result with the same date.

P/S: The last 2 record will always return the same date. Which mean there will be 2 date on 23/9/2015.

Sorry that I couldn't post image so I have to link it to my google drive.
[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznisTJMeHn1VWdzVVIzcTBWbG8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your image isnt public. And if you provide a [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/256da/8) we can find an answer much easier. Also please provide sample data and desire output
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I share the image to public already. The desire output and sample is on the image itself. The image should be explain well about my trouble. thanks!

Comment: Looks good but the problem is we cant copy/paste from a picture. That is why I suggest a SqlFiddle, that save us a lot of time.

Comment: Not so sure how it really work, but I tried to create a sample schema with some dummy data into it. Due to my DB consist a ton of record so I only pick 50 record only.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/252ba/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL allows your posted query but would fail in practically all RDMS SQL engines because you select items with `*` not restricted to the `GROUP BY` clause in an aggregate query. Had you had set [sql_mode to ANSI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/compatibility.html) this query would give the `GROUP BY` error.

Consider the corrected ANSI-syntax of your aggregate query, selecting only those fields you intend to aggregate and then group by the date, cash_info, and other_info fields.

```
SELECT DT, 
       CASH_INFO, 
       Sum(TOTAL_CASH), 
       OTHER_INFO, 
       Sum(TOTAL_CHEQUE), 
       Sum(TOTAL_CREDIT)
FROM (
      SELECT DATE(MAX(RECEIVED)) DT,
             INFO CASH_INFO,
             SUM(IF(TRANS_TYPE = 714, AMOUNT, 0)) TOTAL_CASH,
             '' AS OTHER_INFO,
             0 AS TOTAL_CHEQUE,
             0 AS TOTAL_CREDIT
      FROM PAYMENT
      WHERE LOGIN = 'opensys' 
        AND SOURCE_OF_TRX = '245T2' 
        AND RET_CODE_ID IN (0, 106, 110) 
        AND RECEIVED >= DATE_SUB('2015-09-23 16:30:42', INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
        AND TRANS_TYPE = 714
      GROUP BY INFO
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(MAX(RECEIVED)) DT,
             '' AS CASH_INFO,
             0 AS TOTAL_CASH,    
             INFO OTHER_INFO,
             SUM(IF(TRANS_TYPE = 715, AMOUNT, 0)), -- TOTAL_CHEQUE,
             SUM(IF(TRANS_TYPE = 716, AMOUNT, 0)) -- TOTAL_CREDIT
      FROM PAYMENT
      WHERE LOGIN = 'opensys' 
        AND SOURCE_OF_TRX = '245T2' 
        AND RET_CODE_ID IN (0, 106, 110) 
        AND RECEIVED >= DATE_SUB('2015-09-23 16:30:42', INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
        AND TRANS_TYPE in (715, 716)
      GROUP BY INFO
     ) A
GROUP BY DT, CASH_INFO, OTHER_INFO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the point out, but the result is not really what I wanted. Due to the MAX(CASH_INFO) and Max(OTHER_INFO), the result did not display 2 different batchID as I show in the picture. At the end of day there will be 2 record with same date but different batchID return from the query result.

Comment: Straightforward fix. Simply add `CASH_INFO` and `OTHER_INFO` as group by fields with no aggregation. See my edit.